# Getting Unparseable date error when trying to parse a timeStamp calculated by System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, date, time, date-difference

One of my file name is appended with a timestamp. That timestamp was calculated using `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Now I want to get time difference between timestamp of that file and current system time. I am getting this error:

> Unparseable date: "1509083378768"

Where `1509083378768` is actually a timestamp attached with file name.
Below is my code snippet:

```
 private void calculateTimeDifference(String fileTimeStamp){
    Date fileTimeStampDate ;

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date currentDate = new Date(currentTime);
    long timeDifference = 0 ;

    try {
        fileTimeStampDate = formatter.parse(fileTimeStamp);
        timeDifference = (currentDate.getTime() - fileTimeStampDate.getTime())/1000 ;

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LOG.info("message='{}' {}", "Time Difference is", timeDifference);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are sticking with the old, outdated and not very programmer-friendly classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`? If you need date-time classes (which according to [assylias’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46969215/5772882) you may not do), I warmly recommend [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: `long timeDifference = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong(fileTimeStamp));` Running just now I got 8134.

Comment: Thanks Ole... I didn't know about the easy way. Thanks for sharing latest stuff.

Answer (score 3):

A `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")` can parse a string like `10:15:25`, which is not the format of your tinmestamp so it can't work.

Your timestamp is a number of millis since the epoch and you can use it directly to create a `Date`:

```
Date fileTimeStampDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(fileTimeStamp));
```

Also I'm not sure why you use a date at all since you go back to milliseconds with `getTime`.

So you could get rid of most of your code and simply write:

```
timeDifference = (currentTime - Long.parseLong(fileTimeStamp)) / 1000;
```